# Renouncing your citizenship but the government doesn't accept; can you still get a stateless person passport from Germany?

Tags: germany, passport, turkish-citizens, stateless

I'm just curious:

It is been claimed [here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/cant-renounce-my-citizenship-due-to-being-a-deserter-can-i-apply-for-a-german#comment34630_21199) that the requirement of having renounced your current citizenship to get German citizenship can be accomplished by simply applying to your current government to renounce your citizenship. The user suggests that, to the German government, whether Turkish government allows you to renounce your citizenship or not is irrelevant, meaning that, during the German citizenship application process, even if you provide them with your renunciation application form with a big "Denied" stamp on it, the German government will consider you a stateless person, hence allow you to become a German citizen (provided that you satisfy all the other criteria).

First of all, does this true? Can you give any formal reference?

Secondly, does this mean that, after "renouncing" your citizenship, can the same person apply for a stateless person (grey) passport from the German government?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not the case. Germany will not consider you stateless.

In certain circumstances, Germany will **tolerate** dual citizenship upon nationalization.

Some countries don't allow a renunciation at all.

Some countries make it very difficult.

For 2nd, 3rd generation Turks, court rulings have allowed such exceptions (Military service deemed unreasonable): [2010-10-26: Einbürgerung ohne türkischen Militärdienst | Rechtslupe](https://www.rechtslupe.de/verwaltungsrecht/einbuergerung-ohne-tuerkischen-militaerdienst-323738).

So it allways depends on the specific situation.

The second part of your question has been answered here: [germany - What happens to my German residence permit if I renounce my citizenship? Would it affect my ability to get permanent residence later on? - Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/21202/17166)